# their home vs their own home

Tags: expressions

Let's think about two sentences.
first :

> Italian doctors are now treating coronavirus patients in their homes

second :

> Italian doctors are now treating coronavirus patients in their own homes

My interpretation of these sentences :
first : Doctors are treating patients in patients' homes.
second : Patients are treated in doctors' homes.

Am I right ?

Comment: In the first, you're interpreting "their" as referring to the patients. Why would you interpret it as referring to the doctors in the second case?

Comment: Both sentences share the same ambiguity.

Comment: I agree with Isabel. Both statements are ambiguous. I know one Italian doctor, retired, who sees patients  on appointment in his (own) home.

Comment: Do you know, I think that there _is_ a slight skewing of the 'default' interpretation (you're forced to make a guess at gunpoint as to what the rather careless newscaster meant) in the way you suggest, but I'd hope the gunman was only interested in my guessing and not my accuracy. Although you can see many statements as being ambiguous if you try hard enough, these examples don't take much effort. // The 'own' is an 'amazement marker', and I'd really expect an exclamation mark. The more surprising scenario would be that the doctors are opening up their own families to greater risk.